# Generate N sequential equidistant Lab colors from dark to light

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, lab-color-space

What I’m trying to do is create equidistant/sequential colors using the LAB colorspace. There are similar questions out there asking how to do it but not specific to LAB.

Essentially the ideal function would allow you to give it a single Lab color and it would give you the light and dark shades of that color until it reaches the maximum lightness/darkness. Ideally, I’d be able to give it a second parameter of how many shades to create.

I’m able to create those light to dark colors using RGB. However, I am not sure how to do it using the LAB colorspace. I’m using Python.

Here is the function I have so far:

```
def color_variant(self, target_hex, offset=50):
    if len(target_hex) != 7:
        return None
    hex_color = [target_hex[x:x+2] for x in [1, 3, 5]]
    new_rgb = [int(hex_value, 16) + offset for hex_value in hex_color]
    new_rgb = [min([255, max([0, i])]) for i in new_rgb]

    return '#%02x%02x%02x' % (new_rgb[0], new_rgb[1], new_rgb[2])
```

**Update**
Adding an image to demonstrate how the gradients would look. The image shows two tests: one created using an HSB slider and one using the L of LAB slider.

[image]

Comment: Lab has a simple L = lightness co-ordinate so you want colors where L is variant and a,b are invariant?  Convert to Lab,  vary on L, convert back to rgb?  You need a function to convert RGB -> LAB and back?

Comment: @WarrenP the color conversions are easy. What I don't understand is how to do is evenly space out the distances between the color so that they're equidistant to the brightest (white) and darkest (black) versions of each color. I've added an image to show you where the problem lies in trying to simply just change L. I believe that changing simply just the L won't actually give you steps all the way to black or all the way to white... Seems like you have to also change A and B to properly account for full brightness/darkness.

Comment: equidistant per human perception, or equidistant per photons per square centimeter?

Comment: ie,see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKnqECcg6Gw

Comment: if you change a,b you change the actual color (per LAB model) not its brightness. LAB model is a model for one color space and its associated brightnesses. it's a model, it's not the same as how humans perceive color which is a separate and vague subject.

Comment: I'm not sure I can answer "human perception, or equidistant per photons per square centimeter" with confidence because I haven't tested the results of each... I'm essentially mapping any color as an input, to a predefined set of colors and trying to eliminate mismatched colors, eg: red matched to purple, but it's actually red, purple just was equated to being closer because there was no other red that was closer than the purple.

Comment: I think what you'll find is there is no objective way to eliminate mismatched colors, because even among non colorblind people, these color perceptions vary.